# Getting 0 id with section[id]

Tags: android, mysqli

I been doing this database for a whole night and I cant figure out why i keep get 0 for the order id in table cart when i place order from Android application. The thing that insert into the both table is no problem but just for the orderid in cart table which always return 0 in table.

**cart**

```
<?php
require "connection.php";
session_start();
$foodname=$_POST["food_name"];
$cartquantity=$_POST["cart_quantity"];
$id=$_POST["id"];
$pickuptime=$_POST["pick_up_time"];
$orderid= $_SESSION["last_id"];


$mysqli_qry="insert into cart (orderid,foodname,cartquantity,id,pickuptime) 
values ('$orderid','$foodname','$cartquantity','$id','$pickuptime')";

if ($conn->query($mysqli_qry,$mysqli_qry1)==TRUE){
echo "Insert Successful";

}
else {
echo "Error:".$mysqli_qry."<br>".$conn->error;
}

?>
```

**order**

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, 
$password);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
session_start();
$id=$_POST["id"];
$pickuptime=$_POST["pick_up_time"];
$pickupdate=$_POST["pick_up_date"];
$amount=$_POST["amount"]; 

$mysqli_qry="insert into `order` (`id`,`pickuptime`,`pickupdate`,`amount`) 
values ($id,$pickuptime,$pickupdate,$amount)";

$conn->exec($mysqli_qry);
$_SESSION["last_id"] == $conn->lastInsertId();

?>
```

**Update**
For my Android part

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
    context=ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...params){
    String type=params[0];
    String order_url="http://192.168.28.1/restaurant/orderdb.php";
    String cart_url="http://192.168.28.1/restaurant/cartdb.php";
    if (type.equals("order")){
        try{
            String id=params[1];
            String pick_up_time=params[2];
            String pick_up_date=params[3];
            String amount=params[4];
            URL url=new URL(order_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String post_data= URLEncoder.encode("id","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("pick_up_time","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pick_up_time,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("pick_up_date","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pick_up_date,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("amount","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(amount,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result+=line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (type.equals("cart")){
        try{
            String food_name=params[1];
            String cart_quantity=params[2];
            String id=params[3];
            String pick_up_time=params[4];
            URL url=new URL(cart_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String post_data= URLEncoder.encode("food_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(food_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("cart_quantity","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(cart_quantity,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("id","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("pick_up_time","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pick_up_time,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result+=line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Its not possible to check errors in your code without seeing your Android code.

Comment: I had updated for my android part

Comment: What is your `post_data`? Did you log your post data to see if the `post_data` has been built properly?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the `orderid` variable in `params` and it is missing from `post_data`.

Comment: how can i define orderid in params =.section id? Sorry for silly question. I really confused to these.